# How to choose between private member and let binding?

Tags: f#

When writing a private method that has no need to access other members of the same class, how do you choose between private member and let binding?

- I tend to use private members because it's easier to change accessibility if required, but are there other aspects to keep in mind when making the choice?
- Are let bindings compiled as private members (making this only a style choice)?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The relevant portion of the spec is section [8.6.2](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/cambridge/projects/fsharp/manual/spec.html#_Toc270597548). It states:

> The compiled representation used for values declared in “let”
>   bindings in classes is either:
>
> - A value that is local to the object constructor (if the value is
>     not a syntactic function, is not mutable and is not used in any
>     function or member).
> - An instance field in the corresponding CLI type (if the value is
>     not a syntactic function, but is used in some function or member).
> - A member of the corresponding CLI type (if the value is a
>     syntactic function).

Also:

> Non-function let-bindings that are not used in either the members of
>   a type or a function binding are optimized away and become values that
>   are local to the resulting CLI constructor. Likewise, function
>   bindings are represented as instance members.

I prefer `let` bindings to private members because they're more "functional," i.e., they emphasize "what" over "how." The compiler takes care of the optimal compiled form.

Answer (score 7):

`let` bindings in a class are private.  The main difference I think of between `let` and a private `member` are that `let` bindings cannot be overloaded, and are called with `name()` rather than `this.Name()`.  As such, I think it's a mostly stylistic choice.

Answer (score 3):

`let` bindings cannot be accessed through the class instance but `private method` can.  For examples:

```
type A() =
    let someUtil() = "util code"

    member private this.AnotherUtil() = "anotherUtil"

    member private this.DoSomething() =
       let anotherA = A()
       A.someUtil()  // compilation failed
       A.AnotherUtil() // ok
```