# Call base member in lambda function from inherited class constructor?

Tags: f#

I have a base class

```
type MyBase() =
    let param = myfun()
    member this.Param = param


type MyInherited() =
    inherit MyBase()
    do
         base.Param.DoSomething() // cannot access base in let or do binding.
```

I would like to call `DoSomething` exact once during the inherited object instantiation. But here I am not allowed. What shall I do then?

Do I have to create a method

```
     member this.DoSomething() = base.Param.DoSomething()
```

and call it in the constructor?

```
type MyInherited() as self =
    inherit MyBase()
    do
         self.DoSomething()
```

It feels a bit weird, and duplicated

#### Update

My initial simplified example is not appropriate. Check the followings:

```
type MyBase() =
    let param = "test"
    member this.Param = param

type MyInherited() =
    inherit MyBase()
    do
       (fun () -> base.Param) () |> ignore  // Doesn't work, 
   // A protected member is called or 'base' is being used. 
   // This is only allowed in the direct implementation of members
   // since they could escape their object scope.


type MyInherited() as self =
    inherit MyBase()
    do
       (fun () -> self.Param) () |> ignore  // Works
```

Now actually it is a lot better, all I need to do is to use `self` instead of `base`...(I don't have to redefine `Param` since it is already inherited.)

The reason why F# has such restriction is explained here:

[why is base only possible in private members?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22121335/why-is-base-only-possible-in-private-members)

But I am still not clear why `base` cannot be used in a closure, although it is accessible in a simple let binding.

Comment: What is the type of Param property? What is the return value of DoSomething()? I cannot reproduce your case. It seems work for simple properties

Answer (score 6, accepted):

your initial code was perfectly valid.  You don't have to define a method first that calls through to a base.

This works:

```
do 
  this.DoSomething()
member this.DoSomething() = base.DoSomething()
```

but this avoids duplication like you mentioned:

```
do 
  base.DoSomething()
```

This is what was tripping you up -- constructors can not have a return value.  If the last statement in a sequence has a return, F# assumes that the function has a return of whatever that value/type is.  However, this can not act contrary to a method signature if explicitly defined.  So F# asks you to be explicit about your intention in such a case.  If your intention is to throw away the return of base.DoSomething(), use the pipe-to-ignore operator combination of **|>** **ignore** like this:

```
do
  base.DoSomething() |> ignore
```

Let's put this another way, **if** a *functions' purpose* is to *return a value with no side effects,* and if this value is consequently not used, then we can safely conclude that the function doesn't need to be called in the constructor.  So the compiler / interactive environment warns you about that.  That's what F# is encouraging here.

To be fair, that's not immediately obvious, unless you take the following into account: **do** [compiles all such statements into the primary constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd483473.aspx).  If you check out the F# OO-style for [constructor overloading](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233192.aspx) it might be clearer where the **unit** * signature was coming from.

Normally, having implicitly defined return value makes writing function a more fluid experience... as Rich Hickey puts it, it is just down to familiarity now.

- another name for unit in other languages is **void**

---

### Update

Possibly a compiler constraint is being applied in an overeager fashion, or probably behind-the-scenes the do is defined as a closure before getting unwound and applied to the constructor by the compiler.  The closure would be able to see the **this**, but a method / constructor gets a **this** *and a* **base**.  That's not very intuitive is it?  It seems like you've found a rough edge that needs some sanding.  Please consider making a [feature request](https://visualfsharp.codeplex.com/workitem/list/basic).  F# is now completely open source, so it is worthwhile documenting cases like this.

I did a short exercise on this.  While **this** can be used in a constructor, that will not be adequate when there's an override.  I *think* the following might be a decent way forward (see the **new()** block at the end).

```
[<AbstractClass>]
type MyBase()  =
    let letValue = "let value"
    abstract Method : unit -> string
    default this.Method() = "test"
    member this.Method2() = "Param2"

type MyInherited(param : string) as this =
    inherit MyBase()

    // let localLetValue() = this.letValue      // fails.  let values are private members

    do
      //(fun () -> base.Param) () |> ignore     // Error: The 'base' keyword is used in an invalid way. Base calls cannot be used in closures. Consider using a private member to make base calls.  
      (fun () -> this.Method) () |> ignore       // succeeds -- takes local
      (fun () -> this.base_Method) () |> ignore  // succeeds -- takes base
      (fun () -> this.Method2) () |> ignore      // succeeds -- takes base

    override this.Method() = "ABCdefHIJ"
    member this.base_Method() = base.Method()

    new() as this =
      let a = base.Method()                     // succeeds
      let b = this.Method()                     // succeeds
      MyInherited("some value")
```

Comment: Thank you. My previous question wasn't very clear and I have updated it. However, your answer is still enlightening and certainly would help me in the future.

Comment: @colinfang: yw.  I did an update in response.  See the **new()** section.  I think that this might be a way of getting what you want.

Answer (score 2):

This works:

```
type MyInherited2() =
    inherit MyBase()

    let p = base.Param

    do
        (fun () -> p) () |> ignore
```

The problem in your MyInherited example was due to the fact that `base.Param` was being captured in a closure. This works in a let binding, because for all intents and purposes a let binding in object constructor is a direct implementation of a member.

But you're right about inheritance feeling weird. It's a big can of worms in F# and best to keep it dead simple if you can't avoid it altogether.

Answer (score 1):

Cannot reproduce. For example this is working for me:

```
type MyBase() =
    let param = "test"
    let param' = fun _ -> printfn "test'"
    member this.Param = param
    member this.Param' = param'

type MyInherited() =
    inherit MyBase()
    do
       printfn "%s" (base.Param.ToString()) 
       base.Param'()

let inh = new MyInherited()
```