# Why does "let" in a F# constructor create a private member instead of a local variable

Tags: f#

I'm learning me some F#, and I'm trying to figure out how constructors work.

I want to write a class that takes some input data, parses it, and makes the results available to the outside world via member variables. The parsing process is non-trivial, so I want to create some local variables along the way, but how can I do that without them becoming private member variables, as well? AFAICT, using `let` to create a private member variable is [almost the same](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7778228/how-to-choose-between-private-member-and-let-binding) as using `member private`, but I don't want these temporary variables to pollute the object's namespace.

This is the best I've been able to come up with, so far:

```
type MyClass( inputData ) = 

    let _parsedData = 
        // simulate expensive parsing of the input data
        let work = sprintf "< %s >" inputData
        sprintf "[%s]" work

    member this.parsedData = _parsedData

    member this.dump () = 

        // this doesn't compile (as expected)
        //printfn "work = %s" work

        // I want this to *not* compile (because _parsedData is a local variable in the constructor)
        printfn "_parsedData = %s" _parsedData

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv = 
    let obj = MyClass "hello, world!"
    printfn "obj.parsedData = %s" obj.parsedData
    obj.dump()
    0
```

But `_parsedData` becomes a private member variable, which is not necessary since it's just a temporary working variable, and the final value is stored in `this.parsedData`. The SO post I linked to above suggests that variables created using `let` will act as local variables and be discarded, *as long as they are not referenced in other members*, but the act of defining `this.parsedData` to return `_parsedData` is enough to keep `_parsedData` alive.

I could use lazy evaluation:

```
let _parsedDataLazy = lazy ( 
    // simulate expensive parsing of the input data
    let work = sprintf "< %s >" inputData
    sprintf "[%s]" work
) 

member this.parsedDataLazy = _parsedDataLazy.Value
```

but this doesn't really help, since it still has the problem of `_parsedDataLazy` becoming a private member variable (although in this case, it makes sense). This approach also means keeping `inputData` alive until the first time `parsedDataLazy` is called, which may not be desirable/possible.

I also thought of using `val` to define the member variable, then execute the parsing code to populate it, but `do` bindings have to appear before any `member`'s :-/

I just want to be able to use local variables in a constructor, to calculate a value, then store it in the object. Why does `let` create a private member variable, given that there's already a way of doing that?! The purpose of a constructor is to initialize the object being created, it's just a function, so I don't get why there are these special restrictions on when code can be executed, or different behaviour (e.g. if I use `let` to define a new variable in a member function, it doesn't get hoisted into the object as a member variable).

As an aside, if I create a private member variable in the constructor using `let`, like this:

```
let _foo = 42
```

then I access it like this:

```
let member this.printFoo () =
    printfn "_foo = %s" _foo // no "this"
```

But if I create it like this:

```
member private _foo = 42
```

then I access it like this:

```
let member this.printFoo () =
    printfn "_foo = %s" this._foo // uses "this"
```

This different syntax suggests that the former is creating a closure over the constructor, and keeping the `_foo` variable alive for the life of the object, rather than `_foo` actually being member of the object. Is this what's actually happening?

Comment: `member val parsedData = body of _parsedData`

Comment: This does the parse every time ```parsedData``` is called. It's expensive, so I want to do it _once_, store the result, and then just return it each time it's needed.

Comment: Also, ```inputData``` is actually a ```Stream``` (a sequence of objects are being read out of a file), so the parse _has_ to be done at construction time.

Comment: But these are implementation details. I'm actually looking to understand exactly what's happening when these things get constructed. My background is C++ and Python (and C/assembler before that), and constructors there are just functions that initialize a new object. Yes, there are problems with this approach e.g. what happens if an exception is thrown half-way, and you end up with a partially-constructed object (I suspect this is why there are rules about when ```do``` blocks can run), but there's something different going on here, and I'm try to get a handle on that.

Comment: according to documentation** member val ** is only evaluated once on the object creation time, why do you think it should be evaluated on every call?

Answer (score 0):

To answer @konst-sh's question *"why do you think it should be evaluated on every call?"*, I don't think it should, but that's not what I'm seeing.

My understanding is that for the code below, the 3 statements that make up `parsedData` are an expression, that evaluates to a string (the output of `sprintf`), that is stored in a member variable.

```
type MyClass( inputData ) =

    member this.parsedData =
        // simulate expensive parsing of the input data
        printfn "PARSE"
        let work = sprintf "< %s >" inputData
        sprintf "[%s]" work

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv =
    let obj = MyClass "hello, world!"
    printfn "CONSTRUCTED"
    printfn "obj.parsedData = %s" obj.parsedData
    printfn "obj.parsedData = %s" obj.parsedData
    0
```

But when I run it, I get this:

```
CONSTRUCTED
PARSE
obj.parsedData = [< hello, world! >]
PARSE
obj.parsedData = [< hello, world! >]
```

I would expect to see this:

```
PARSE
CONSTRUCTED
obj.parsedData = [< hello, world! >]
obj.parsedData = [< hello, world! >]
```

Stepping through in VSCode also confirms that the 3 statements get executed twice. But `parseData` is *not* a function, right? For that, I would need to define it like this:

```
    member this.parsedData () =
        ...
```

It feels like I'm missing something fundamental here... :-)

Comment: `member val`, not `member`

Comment: Sigh... That was it. Gotta love those overloaded keywords :-/ For anyone else looking, the magic words are [auto-implemented properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/members/properties).

Thanks guys.